# DiscordAPIError: 404: Not Found, Reaction roles

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord.js, bots

v13,
I'm trying to do Reaction roles, but it gives me this error:

> throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);

> DiscordAPIError: 404: Not Found
> at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
> at async ChannelManager.fetch (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord

> Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ChannelManager.js:114:18)
> at async module.exports (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\utils\EditMessage.js:10:21) {

EditMessage.js file code:

```
const addReactions = (message, reactions) => {
    message.react(reactions[0])
    reactions.shift()
    if(reactions.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(() => addReactions(message, reactions), 500)
    }
}

module.exports = async (client, id, text, reactions = []) => {
    const channel = await client.channels.fetch(id) // Send Message In Channel ID Provided

    channel.messages.fetch().then((messages) => {
        if(messages.size === 0) {
            // Send Message In Channel ID Provided
            // Send Text
            message.channel.send(text).then((message) => {
                // Add Reaction
                addReactions(message, reactions)
            })
        } else {
            // Edit Message After Sent
            for(const message of messages) {
                //Edit Text
                message[1].edit(text)
                // Edit Reaction
                addReactions(message[1], reactions)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

setup.js file code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const EditMessage = require('../../utils/EditMessage')

module.exports = (client) => {
    EditMessage(client, '798996288258703382', new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Role Menu: Editing Program')
    .setColor('#000000')
    .setDescription(`React to give yourself a role.
1️⃣ After Effects
2️⃣ Video Star
3️⃣ Alight Motion
4️⃣ Sony Vegas
    `)
    .setFooter('Reaction Roles')
    , ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣']
    )
}
```